# Função que determina se todas as letras contidas em uma string estão na outra

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    certas =0
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in lettersGuessed:
            certas += 1

    #print(certas)

    if certas == len(secretWord):
        return True


    else:
        return False

secretWord = 'durian' 
#lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
#lettersGuessed = ['e', 'a', 'l', 'p', 'e']
#isWordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u'])
lettersGuessed = ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u']
print(isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
```

Objetivo é determinar se todas as letras de `secretWord` estão contidas em `lettersGuessed`.

O meu código está funcionando. Existe alguma maneira Pythonica de fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá pra fazer em uma linha:

```
def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
     return all([letter in letters_guessed for letter in secret_word])

print(is_word_guessed('abcd',  ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']))  # True

print(is_word_guessed('abcd',  ['a', 'b', 'e', 'c']))  # False
```

A função `all` retorna True se todos os valores na lista passada pra ela forem True, e False se um ou mais dos valores for False.

A compreensão de lista analisa cada letra em `secret_word` e adiciona um elemento True se a letra analisada está em `letters_guessed` e False se não.

Comment: all é uma função?

Comment: Sim. Nem precisa importar nada. Vale a pena conhecer [`all` e a irmã dela `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: Você pode remover os colchetes dentro de `all` para, ao invés de criar uma lista, criar um gerador. Assim o interpretador só precisará avaliar até encontrar o primeiro `false`, o que pode economizar tempo e memória da aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de fazer:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    return set(secretWord).issubset(set(lettersGuessed))
```

A vantagem que vejo nesse caso é poupar a verificação de caracteres repetidos.

Veja por exemplo:

```
secretWord = 'aaaabcdddefg'
lettersGuessed = 'abcdefg'
```

Ao usar `all()`, está percorrendo `secretWord` 12 vezes e `lettersGuessed` até 7 vezes para cada uma dessas 12. (Este é um caso simples de poucos caracteres e onde as strings estão ordenadas).

Comment: E para se gerar um `set` não são percorridos todos os caracteres? Da forma que colocou, seria como `set` não ser O(n).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, de fato. Só que é melhor voce ter possíveis `12+7` iterações do que `12*7` (no pior caso), não acha? Lembre também que o tempo médio de execução de uma interseção entre conjuntos é de: `O(min(len(s), len(t))`

Comment: Sim, acredito que sim. Preciso ler a fundo para ter certeza, mas parece-me que tens razão quanto a isso. Eu havia respondido desta forma também, mas acabei não publicando por desejar analisar melhor e acabei esquecendo.